# Question marks in output of command "ls -la" in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, nginx, logging, permissions, ls

When I write `ls -la` o the command line, I get this output:

```
ls -la /var/log/nginx

d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? access.log
```

for all files in this folder.

When I do it for another folder:

```
ls -la /var/log/nginx_back/

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       4096 Апр 25 11:06 .
drwxrwxr-x 15 root ssh        4096 Май  1 00:29 ..    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  220793880 Апр 25 11:04 access.log-20170401.gz
```

Everything is ok.

Permissions on the directory above:

```
drw-r--r--  2 nginx     adm        69632 Май  1 00:29 nginx    
drwxr-xr-x  2 root      root        4096 Апр 25 11:06 nginx_back
```

I have these question marks only when I'm not root.

I've added my user to the group `nginx`, added all permissions, created another user, but the system doesn't want to show the file's attributes for non-superusers in the directory `/var/log/nginx`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 7):

This issue is a permission problem.  Specifically, it relates to execute bits on directories.

Consider the following example

```
$ mkdir -p remove_execute/remove_execute_test     
$ touch remove_execute/remove_execute_test/test_file.txt 
$ ls -la remove_execute/remove_execute_test/ 
total 8 
drwxrwxr-x 2 zerodf zerodf 4096 Nov 21 10:51 . 
drwxrwxr-x 3 zerodf zerodf 4096 Nov 21 10:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zerodf zerodf    0 Nov 21 10:51 test_file.txt
```

Now, if we remove execute permission on the directory, we can't get the stats.

```
$ sudo chmod a-x remove_execute/remove_execute_test/ 
$ ls -la remove_execute/remove_execute_test/ 
ls: cannot access remove_execute/remove_execute_test/..: Permission denied 
ls: cannot access remove_execute/remove_execute_test/test_file.txt: Permission denied 
ls: cannot access remove_execute/remove_execute_test/.: Permission         denied 
total 0 
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? . 
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test_file.txt
```

Unless we have root permissions.

```
$ sudo ls -la remove_execute/remove_execute_test/
total 8
drw-rw-r-- 2 zerodf zerodf 4096 Nov 21 10:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 zerodf zerodf 4096 Nov 21 10:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zerodf zerodf    0 Nov 21 10:51 test_file.txt
```